# Many Logstash instances reading from Redis

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have one Logstash process running inside one node consuming from a Redis list, but I'm afraid that just one process cannot handle the data throughput without a great delay.

I was wondering if I run one more process for Logstash inside this same machine will perform a little better, but I'm not certain about that. I know that my ES index is not a bottleneck.

Would Logstash duplicate my data, if I consume the same list? This approach seems to be a right thing to do?

Thanks!

Here my input configuration:

```
input {
    redis {
        data_type => "list"
        batch_count => 300
        key => "flight_pricing_stats"
        host => "my-redis-host"
    }
}
```

Comment: `Would Logstash duplicate my data, if I consume the same list?` No it won't. When logstash pulls a message from the redis list, the message is deleted from redis. (We used multiple logstash in production pulling messages from one redis).

Answer (score 2):

You could try adjusting logstash input threads, if you are going to run another logstash process in the same machine. Default is 1.

```
input {
    redis {
        data_type => "list"
        batch_count => 300
        key => "flight_pricing_stats"
        host => "my-redis-host"
        threads => 2
    }
}
```

You could run more than one logstash against the same redis, events should not get duplicated. But I'm not sure that would help.

If you're not certain whats going on, I recommend the [logstash monitoring API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring-logstash.html). It can help you narrow down your real bottlenck.

And also an interesting post from elastic on the subject: [Logstash Lines Introducing a benchmarking tool for Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-lines-2017-08-01)